# Pytest-django: set user permissions

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I work on a library for Django using pytest 3.0.6 and pytest-django 3.1.2. I have this very simple test failing, and I don't understand what happen:

```
# test_mytest.py
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_user_has_perm(django_user_model):
    # Create a new user
    john_doe = django_user_model.objects.create_user('johndoe', email='jd@example.com', password='123456')

    # Get or create the permission to set on user
    user_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth', model='user')
    p, _ = Permission.objects.get_or_create(content_type=user_ct, codename='delete_user', name="Can delete user")

    # User don't have the permission
    assert john_doe.has_perm(p) is False

    # Set permission to user
    john_doe.user_permissions.add(p)
    assert john_doe.has_perm(p) is True  # ---> FAIL
```

Just in case, the result of the test is:

```
$ pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.5.3, pytest-3.0.6, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
Django settings: testsite.settings (from ini file)
rootdir: D:\Dev\foss\django-modern-rpc, inifile: tox.ini
plugins: pythonpath-0.7.1, django-3.1.2, cov-2.4.0
collected 1 items

modernrpc\tests\test_test_test.py F

================================== FAILURES ===================================
_____________________________ test_user_has_perm ______________________________

django_user_model = <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_user_has_perm(django_user_model):
        # Create a new user
        john_doe = django_user_model.objects.create_user('johndoe', email='jd@example.com', password='123456')

        # Get or create the permission to set on user
        user_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth', model='user')
        p, _ = Permission.objects.get_or_create(content_type=user_ct, codename='delete_user', name="Can delete user")

        # User don't have the permission
        assert john_doe.has_perm(p) is False

        # Set permission to user
        john_doe.user_permissions.add(p)
>       assert john_doe.has_perm(p) is True  # ---> FAIL
E       assert False is True
E        +  where False = <bound method PermissionsMixin.has_perm of <User: johndoe>>(<Permission: auth | user | Can delete user>)
E        +    where <bound method PermissionsMixin.has_perm of <User: johndoe>> = <User: johndoe>.has_perm

modernrpc\tests\test_test_test.py:20: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.32 seconds ===========================
```

The config block, from tox.ini:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = testsite.settings
norecursedirs = .git __pycache__ build dist venv* .tox .vscode .cache *.egg-info
python_paths = modernrpc/tests
testpaths = modernrpc/tests
python_files = test_*.py dummy_*.py
```

And the DB configuration, from test settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'modern_rpc.sqlite3'),
    },
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a string `'app_label.codename'`:

> Returns True if the user has the specified permission, where perm is in the format "<app label>.<permission codename>".

Also, you must clear `user._perm_cache` and `user._user_perm_cache` if you have changed permissions since the last call to `has_perm`or retrieve a new instance of this user from the db to make sure there are no caches:

```
 del john_doe._perm_cache
 del john_doe._user_perm_cache 
 # OR
 john_doe = django_user_model.objects.get(username='johndoe')
```

This is because `has_perm` will call the auth backend which in turn will consult these caches first.

Comment: Thank you for this, I totally missed the cache system for permissions.

Comment: Yeah. Django makes you dig through the code there as the caching is not well documented.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm):

> has_perm(perm, obj=None)
>
> Returns True if the user has the specified permission, where perm is in the format
>
> `"<app label>.<permission codename>"`.
>
> (see documentation on permissions). If the user is inactive, this method
>   will always return False.
>
> If obj is passed in, this method won’t check for a permission for the model, but for this specific object.

So this method accepts string not a permission object

`john_doe.has_perm('auth.delete_user')`

should return `True`. (The `delete_user` permission has the `auth` app assigned, because you have used `user_ct` to create it, where `user_ct`'s app is `auth`).

However in your example this won't immediately happen, because there is also a [permission check caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching).

It will work after you refetch your object

```
#Be aware this only works after Django 1.9+
#https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26514
john_doe.refresh_from_db()
#Otherwise use:
john_doe = User.objects.get(pk=john_doe.pk)
```

Comment: Good answer. I did run in to a situation where `refresh_from_db` did not work, even in Django 3.2. I had to use `User.objects.get`.